# Using several classes with same name (DotRas) in one assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I have an issue about using DotRas in my assembly. Where is a several versions of DotRas for each platform (WinXP, 7, 8 etc). The problem is all libs has the same class and namespace names. So if i add reference to all of them and trying to use them, VS says for example `Ambiguous reference: DotRas.RasPhoneBook`
So is it possible to solve the problem in one assembly? Or I only need to create wrap asseblies for each DotRas class.

Comment: i found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx! It possible to change alias in Property of reference by VS! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Steps: 1) add all needed references 2) type at begin of file: `extern alias AliasName` where AliasName is Alias you typed in properties of library in VS. Using is: `AliasName.MyClass sample = new AliasName.MyClass();` etc

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use alias names for different platforms (WinXP, 7, 8 etc)? 
In using statement.
It should resolve your problem.

```
using colAlias = System.Collections;
namespace System
{
 class TestClass
 {
    static void Main()
    {
        // Searching the alias:
        colAlias::Hashtable test = new colAlias::Hashtable();

        // Add items to the table.
        test.Add("A", "1");
        test.Add("B", "2");
        test.Add("C", "3");

        foreach (string name in test.Keys)
        {
            // Searching the global namespace:
            global::System.Console.WriteLine(name + " " + test[name]);
        }
    }
}}
```

Complete example is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx

Also there is MS link for using namespaces:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx

Comment: You should include an example within your answer to preserve your answer in the event the link breaks or the website is unavailable

Comment: Its not working becouse VS dont know what kind of reference to use. Again - all libraries has the same namespaces not only class names.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. In that case extern alias should be used. Glad that you found the answer.